# JSON splitting down two different paths

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Good day all,

I am looking create a JSON script that will allow objects to either fetch a value or continue down a data path

for example:

```
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : "123"
  }
}
```

In the example above if i get the value of A.B, i get the result of 123. However I also want A to have their own value of for example "XYZ".

So we I say, what is A? It will return "XYZ" and I also say, What is A.B it will return "123"

I hope this makes sense, JSON seems to follow a single path, but i want the ability to follow the path and assign values to each node.  its like the node has a value but it also has children and a parent.

Any help regarding theory is greatly appreciated

Comment: What you are asking is impossible.  JSON is Key:Value based.  A's value is an object with a sole property of `B`.  You would have to add another property in B called `Value` or something, then you can call `A.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign 2 different values to an object property. You could do something like this however:

```
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : "123",
    "value" : "XYZ"
  }
}
```

Referencing `A.value` will return `XYZ` and `A.B` will return `123`

Edit:

If you make `A` a function that returns the value you want, you can then assign properties to `A`. But this is probably a bad practice:

```
let A = function () {
  return 'XYZ';
}

A.B = '123';

let obj = {
  A
};

console.log(A()); // XYZ
console.log(A.B); // 123
```

Comment: hmm i kind of like where you were going with the A.Value.  If i could modify the return type of an object call then i can easily solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom function using `reduce()` method to be able to pass nested keys as a string.

```js
const data = {"A": {"B": "123"}}

const getPath = (path, obj) => {
  return path.split('.').reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    return r[e] || (arr[i + 1] ? {} : undefined)
  }, obj)
}

console.log(getPath('A.B', data))
console.log(getPath('A', data))
console.log(getPath('A.C', data))
```

If you want to always return last found value in path you can use this instead.

```js
const data = {
  "A": {
    "B": "123",
    "C": {"D": 2}
  }
}

const getPath = (path, obj) => {
  return path.split('.').reduce((r, e) => (r[e] || r ), obj)
}

console.log(getPath('A.B', data))
console.log(getPath('A.C.F.G', data))
console.log(getPath('A.B.Q', data))
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I was looking for, its returning the full json rather than the value it holds. I have a feeling what I want isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` stands for `JavaScript Object Notation` and this means a JSON represents an object. Each attribute of an object may only have one value. In your case this is the following:

```
var a = { "A": { "B": "123"}
```

this represents an object like `{ A: { B: 123}` and this means:

```
console.log(a.A) // {B: 123}
console.log(a.A.B) // 123
```

so what you are trying to do is just not possible.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you, i had a feeling it wasn't.

Comment: if it solved your question please mark the answer with the green hook ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem, but it seems like the logic to figure out the JSON string you are looking for should be figured out before the request or by the response. Returning multiple paths of logic doesn’t seem like a good idea.

Comment: I found a solution, however I agree it gets a bit messy. Thank you for your input